# ASP.NET WebApp Authentication Error

Tags: asp.net

I work for a local library that just had a consulting company do a migration of their IIS installation from one server to another.

It wasn't until a few days ago that my boss noticed that login.aspx seemed to have broken. I have little knowledge of ASP.NET but I just have a feeling this is something really simple.

Here is the error when trying to login to the webapp:

```
Error authenticating. Error authenticating user. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

Active Directory was on a completely different machine and was not migrated to different hardware.

The app connects to a sqlexpress server and that is running and the database is there ...

Under `ASP.NET Configuration Settings` the `sqlServerWebConnection` points to the machine running the sql server. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Under `login.aspx.cs` I have

`string adPath = "LDAP://DC=COMPANY,DC=org"; //Path to your LDAP directory server`

**Because the webapp used to run on IIS on the DC, is that the line that somehow needs modified?**

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing all of the code, but it looks like the code is trying to connect into an LDAP server.  They might have been using that DC as a LDAP server for authenticating users.  Again, its hard to tell without the full code.  You might want to try changing the path to your current DC and see what happens. (Make sure you make a backup first.)

Comment: I changed the path to the current DC and I get a similar error (now mentions groups) `Error authenticating. Error obtaining group names. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.`

Comment: Do the groups exist in the new DC??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question before the migration you had a server running as a domain controller with the web app installed on it. Now, after the migration the webapp has been migrated to a new server and the domain controller left running the AD.

Is this right? Could you please verify that the new server is part of the existing domain?

Comment: That is absolutely correct. The new server is not a DC. The new server the application runs on is part of the domain.

Comment: Which version of Windows the new server runs? Is Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Web Server 2008 maybe?

Comment: Don't get too excited: This is IIS 6 on Sv2k3. Both the old and new are 2003.

Comment: mmm... I've had a similar issue from a 2003 server that would connect to a 2008 server. What I do not understand really is why the login box is grayed out...

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean the login box, there is a box that specifies domain and it is the correct domain. It's grayed out so it can't be changed. I should probably edit that out as it seems irrelevant.